# Receving not an aggregate function or GROUP BY error within a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having issues with a sub query within a view. I want to display the 'Form' field which is simply a column that displays a random number between 1 -10. The problem I have is that if you look at the query, I have the following line displayed twice.

```
ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
```

The first time I call the line it performs the random calculation, but the second time I call it, it performs another random calculation, which makes the output incorrect. The reason to call it a second time is simply to output the colum when I call on the view using a select. However, if I simply call it `'Form'` instead of `ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form`, I get an error stating 'Form' is not an aggregate function or in a GROUP BY'.

I can't simply call `'Form'` in a GROUP BY as the output becomes incorrect. Really what I'm asking is how do I output the 'Form' field correctly when I want to SELECT it to show from a view?

Below is the code for the view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TeamWeighting]
AS

    WITH pl AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID
                                ,p.Position
                                ,CASE WHEN p.TeamID = 0 THEN 0
                                      ELSE p.playerWeighting END AS playerWeighting
                                ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
                                ,t.TeamID
                FROM dbo.Fixture f
                INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
                INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
                INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
                WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1)
    ,po AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk FROM pl)
    SELECT TeamID
        ,SUM(po.playerWeighting) AS TeamWeight
        ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
        ,SUM(po.playerWeighting / 10 * Form + po.playerWeighting) AS FinalTeamWeight
    FROM po
    WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk = 1) OR 
            (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
            (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
            (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
            GROUP BY po.TeamID
```

Below is when I call the View, the 'Form' field you see below is calling on the second `'ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form'`

```
SELECT [TeamID], [TeamWeight], [Form], [FinalTeamWeight]
    FROM TeamWeighting
```

UPDATE:

Below is how I want it to look like where each 'TeamID' has one 'Form' assigned to it. The problem with the example below is that like I said because I included the random calculation again, the form numbers are difference to the original count. You can tell by performing the calculation below and realise that the 'FinalWeighting' doesn't match:

1: TeamWeight / 10 
2: Take figure from 1 and multiply by the number displayed in 'Form'
3: Add figure from 2 to the original team weight and you should get your 'FinalTeamWeight'.

Below is how it should be displayed (like I said only problem is calculation doesn't add up:

[image]

If I perform a group by with TeamID and Form, I receive multiple TeamID's (see below and that is not what I want:

[image]

Comment: You're asking for it to sum by TeamID but if form isn't unique to a TeamID then what output are you expecting for form? e.g. for teamID "1", if you have two forms (A and B), what are you expecting it to output? (A, B or both?)

Comment: @ZLK, I provided more details in the question on desired output. Any more inform required just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calculation to actually match you can reverse-calculate a new "TeamForm" from `FinalTeamWeight` and `TeamWeight`:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[TeamWeighting]
AS

WITH pl AS (SELECT DISTINCT p.PlayerID
                           ,p.Position
                           ,CASE WHEN p.TeamID = 0 THEN 0
                                 ELSE p.playerWeighting END AS playerWeighting
                           ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % 10 + 1 AS Form
                           ,t.TeamID
            FROM dbo.Fixture f
            INNER JOIN dbo.League l ON f.LeagueID = l.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Team t ON l.LeagueID = t.LeagueID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Player p ON t.TeamID = p.TeamID
            WHERE f.WeekNumber = 1)
,po AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pl.TeamID, pl.Position ORDER BY NEWID()) AS Rnk FROM pl)
,t AS (SELECT TeamID
             ,SUM(playerWeighting) AS TeamWeight
             ,SUM(playerWeighting / 10 * Form + playerWeighting) AS FinalTeamWeight
       FROM po
       WHERE (po.Position = 'GK' and po.rnk  = 1) OR 
             (po.Position = 'DF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
             (po.Position = 'MF' and po.rnk <= 4) OR
             (po.Position = 'FW' and po.rnk <= 2)
       GROUP BY po.TeamID
)
SELECT TeamID
      ,TeamWeight
      ,10 * (FinalTeamWeight - TeamWeight) / TeamWeight As TeamForm  --< reverse-calculate
      ,FinalTeamWeight
FROM t;
```

Comment: The calculation still doesn't seem to match, unless I am incorrect and the calculation is doing what it suppose to and the way i think it should be calculated is incorrect?

Comment: Updated for the calculation to match.

Comment: @YB, the issue is with this calculation: SUM(playerWeighting / 10 * Form + playerWeighting) AS FinalTeamWeight.

Comment: If you perform the calculation I've commented above with the teamweight as 411, form 3, and finalteamweight 542, you'll see it doesn't add up

Comment: The calculation in your script take a new random Form, so that won't work anyway. The calculation in my script use pl.Form and should be more consistent. You might want to go for `playerWeighting * Form / 10` to improve precision.

Comment: It's tricky to test because you have new random `Form` each time. Try to temporarily substitute `Form` with `PlayerID % 10 + 1` or some such just for testing.

Comment: Ok its working now. Thank you for all your help Y.B :)