# NULL values for when trying to perform an UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to complete a lookup table and keep receiving null values when I want to update the fixtures table. I am assuming that since I tried to change the logic from hard code to lookup table, it isn't working.

Below displays the four tables (from top to bottom):
- Score
- ScoreReference
- Fixture
- TeamWeighting

[image]

I want to try and determine the difference in teamWeighting between both sides for each fixture and based on the weighting, it determines the score to update the 'Fixture' table by selecting a score that matches the goal difference based on the difference of 'TeamWeighting'.

As you can see it displays NULL and I am not sure why this is.

Below is the code of the query that I know is causing the problem:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID
    ) ht --HomeTeam
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID
    ) at --AwayTeam
    WHERE f.HomeScore IS NULL AND f.FixtureDate < GETDATE()
)


UPDATE f 
SET f.HomeScore = s.HomeScore,
    f.AwayScore = s.AwayScore
FROM dbo.Fixture f
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT FixtureID,
    TeamScore,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
        CASE 
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore ORDER BY NEWID())
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN AwayWeighting AND HomeWeighting
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE AwayScore > HomeScore ORDER BY NEWID())
        END AS ScoreID
        FROM dbo.Score s
        LEFT JOIN ScoreReference sr
        ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference

    ) AS ScoreID -- end select case

FROM cte c

 ) -- end inner join

 AS ScoreResult
    ON f.FixtureID = ScoreResult.FixtureID
INNER JOIN Score s
    ON ScoreResult.ScoreID = s.ScoreID
INNER JOIN ScoreReference sr
    ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference


    Select * from dbo.Score
    Select * from dbo.ScoreReference
    SELECT * from dbo.Fixture
    SELECT * From TeamWeighting

END
```

Comment: That's a duplicate of [Receving not an aggregate function or GROUP BY error within a CTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37914484/receving-not-an-aggregate-function-or-group-by-error-within-a-cte)

Comment: Hi Carl.  Try an put an ELSE 0 in the case statement for now. If you get a 0 then you know there is a problem with the CASE Statement.

Comment: @mvisser I will do that for now and update you on what is happening. Thank you

Comment: I put else 0 but all I receive is NULL

Comment: try and replace the left join with inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This should work

```
DECLARE @fixtureID INT,
    @scoreDifference INT

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID
    ) ht --HomeTeam
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID
    ) at --AwayTeam
    WHERE f.HomeScore IS NULL AND f.FixtureDate < GETDATE()
)


SELECT FixtureID, 
    ScoreDifference
INTO #processData
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT c.FixtureID,
            TeamScore, 
            CASE WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN sr.HomeWeighting AND sr.AwayWeighting 
                    THEN sr.ScoreDifference 
                 WHEN TeamScore BETWEEN sr.AwayWeighting  AND sr.HomeWeighting 
                    THEN sr.ScoreDifference 
            END AS ScoreDifference
    FROM cte c
    CROSS APPLY ScoreReference sr
) score
WHERE ScoreDifference IS NOT NULL

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #processData) > 0
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @fixtureID = FixtureID,
        @scoreDifference = ScoreDifference 
    FROM #processData

    UPDATE f
    SET f.HomeScore = score.HomeScore,
     f.AwayScore = score.AwayScore
    FROM
    (
        SELECT TOP 1  HomeScore, 
            AwayScore, 
            @fixtureID AS FixtureID 
        FROM Score s
        WHERE ScoreDifference = @scoreDifference
        ORDER BY NEWID()
    ) AS score
    INNER JOIN Fixture f
        ON f.FixtureID = score.FixtureID

    DELETE #processData
    WHERE FixtureID = @fixtureID

END

    DROP TABLE #processData
```

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. I have just sent you another email a few moments ago before you answer on something you may be interested in. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT f.FixtureID,
        ht.FinalTeamWeight - at.FinalTeamWeight AS TeamScore
    FROM dbo.Fixture f
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.HomeTeamID
    ) ht --HomeTeam
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT tw.FinalTeamWeight
        FROM dbo.TeamWeighting tw
        WHERE tw.TeamID = f.AwayTeamID
    ) at --AwayTeam
    WHERE f.HomeScore IS NULL AND f.FixtureDate < GETDATE()
)


UPDATE f 
SET f.HomeScore = s.HomeScore,
    f.AwayScore = s.AwayScore
FROM dbo.Fixture f
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT FixtureID,
    TeamScore,
    (
        SELECT TOP (1)
        CASE 
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN HomeWeighting AND AwayWeighting
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE HomeScore > AwayScore ORDER BY NEWID())
            WHEN c.TeamScore BETWEEN AwayWeighting AND HomeWeighting
                THEN (SELECT TOP 1 ScoreID FROM dbo.Score WHERE AwayScore > HomeScore ORDER BY NEWID())
        END AS ScoreID
        FROM dbo.Score s
        INNER JOIN ScoreReference sr
        ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference

    ) AS ScoreID -- end select case

FROM cte c

 ) -- end inner join

 AS ScoreResult
    ON f.FixtureID = ScoreResult.FixtureID
INNER JOIN Score s
    ON ScoreResult.ScoreID = s.ScoreID
INNER JOIN ScoreReference sr
    ON s.ScoreDifference = sr.ScoreDifference


    Select * from dbo.Score
    Select * from dbo.ScoreReference
    SELECT * from dbo.Fixture
    SELECT * From TeamWeighting

END
```

Comment: Same issue mvisser. I have got it working hard  coded but not via look up. Don't if you require seeing the hard coded version?

Comment: I've sent it to you via email

Comment: Cool got it.  I dont know whats in the FinalTeamWeight table. First thing, just run a SELECT * FROM cte. Do you get any nulls?

Comment: Also in the Score table are there any NULLS?

Comment: There are no NULLS in the Score table

Comment: If you pass me your schema and data then I can sort it out.  At the moment I see no problem

Comment: Have sent you the schema and table data via email

Comment: Ok, I have the problem.  So you would need to do a while loop, Cursor(Which I dont suggest) or scalar function.  because you are processing a subset of records from the TOP 1, so you always get only the first record.  But you need to process the row one at a time. I can do it if you want

Comment: Yeah sure if you don't mind and I'll give a test. Thank you